# Best practice order posts by published date

Tags: php, mysql

I searched everywhere but I couldn’t get a answer that satisfy my questions.
I want to order MySQL results by published date.

I will explain exactly what I want to do.

All posts are saving to database with following fields

```
Post_id = auto increment 
post_title = varchar
posted_date = datetime (gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s') )
post_status = int
post_published_date = datetime (gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s') )
```

After saving the posts I want display posts order by post_published date. When posts are inserted post_published_date will be NULL and when change the post_status to 1 and post_published_date date will be added.

So I’m ordering posts as below

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_status = 1 ORDER BY post_published_date DESC, Post_id DESC
```

Also tried below

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_status = 1 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(post_published_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
 DESC, Post_id DESC
```

All above works well. My question is which is the best approach from above or is there a better way to do this (performance wise). 
Appreciate your time.

**Edit:** Also i would like to know whether i need to use `STR_TO_DATE` for a MySQL datetime column.

Comment: Only `ORDER BY post_published_date DESC` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Only you can use below query will be best:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_status = 1 ORDER BY post_published_date DESC
```

Comment: what if there is duplicated datetime?

Comment: if two or more datetime are same they arranged sequentially they have entered in database. what you acutely desired to order? if you want order more then two column you can do it, simply
 post_published_date,post_id DESC

Answer (score 0):

best approach is
 `ORDER BY post_published_date DESC` 
 because its simply descending all posts for poststatus =1

Code :

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_status = 1 ORDER BY post_published_date DESC, Post_id DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_status = 1 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(post_published_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
DESC, Post_id DESC
```

Try this query. just removed the semicolon after `STR_TO_DATE` function.
Are you using Wordpress?

Comment: No this is custom. Yes i did. You can see the same code in my questions. I only want to know which is the best approach

Comment: im sorry i mistakenly added semicolon. My queries working fine. Just want to know which will be best preforming query.

Comment: SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_status = 1 ORDER BY post_published_date DESC, Post_id DESC

Comment: SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_status = 1 ORDER BY post_published_date DESC, Post_id DESC 
I checked both queries this is taking less time comapared to the other

Comment: So i dont need to use STR_TO_DATE?

Comment: No, because If your adding in timestamp format also it will work properly

Comment: Are you displaying the date in your front end screen and  if you want that in particular format then only you need to change use STR_TO_DATE